# Convergence of an integral and the asymptotic of the function

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Let $f(x):[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$. Is it true that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx<\infty$ implies $xf(x) \to 0,$ as $ x\to \infty?$

Answer (score 2):

No. It isn't even true, that $f(x) \to 0$ for $x \to \infty$. To see that, define $f \colon [0,\infty) \to [0, \infty)$ by 
$$ 
f(x) = \begin{cases}  1 & x \in \left[n, n+\frac 1{n^2}\right),  n \in \mathbf N - \{0\}\\
   0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $$ \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2} = \frac{\pi^2}6 < \infty $$
but 
$$ 1 = f(n) \not\to 0, \qquad n \to \infty $$

Comment: ... it can be worse, $f$ can be unbounded, for example define $f$ to be $n$ on $[n, n+\frac 1{n^3}]$ and $0$ otherwise.